# flash player wont fit to screen

Tags: css, swfobject

Im using this code to try to get a swf file to "fit" my screen or any screen it is on for that matter, however i have a problem. when using this code the player in both Chrome and IE it streched to fit the screen but the height is not, it's not filling up the screen heightwise, why is the width working while the height is not ?!

```
<style>
player {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
</style>

    <!--[if IE]><object
        id="player"
        type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
        classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"
        codebase="http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab"
    ><![endif]-->
    <!--[if !IE]>--><object
        id="player"
        type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
        codebase="http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab"
        data="/<? echo "$swf"; ?>.swf"
    ><!--<![endif]-->
        <param name="movie" value="/<? echo "$swf"; ?>.swf" />
        <param name="quality" value="high" />
        <param name="scale" value="noborder" />
        <p>
            <a href="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/">
                Adobe Flash Player
            </a> is required to view this content.
        </p>
    </object>
```

EDIT:
If i change  width:100%; & height:100%; to for example 600 on both it works in both IE and Chrome but as soon as i change it too 100% the witdth fits the screen while the Height is screwed and only fit almost half the screen, in IT the rezising wont work at all :<

Comment: Perhaps you should throw up a sample in jsbin?

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS seems to be incorrect. You need to use `#` to select an ID.

```
#player {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

Comment: it was removed by misstake, it still wont work and in IE it will absoloutly not work :(

Answer (score 0):

Your embed flash must be outside from other elements and **html & body** must have a **height** of 100%.

Sample:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
      <head>
           <style type="text/css">
                html, body {
                     height: 100%;
                }

                #player {
                     width: 100%;
                     height: 100%;
                }
           </style>
      </head>
      <body>
           <!--[if IE]><object id="player" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"  codebase="http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab"><![endif]-->
           <!--[if !IE]>--><object id="player" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" codebase="http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab" data="/<? echo "$swf"; ?>.swf"><!--<![endif]-->
           <param name="movie" value="/<? echo "$swf"; ?>.swf" />
           <param name="quality" value="high" />
           <param name="scale" value="noborder" />
           <p>
                <a href="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/">
                     Adobe Flash Player
                </a> is required to view this content.
           </p>
           </object>
      </body>
  </html>
```

Otherwise, use a **fixed** or **absolute** positioning:

```
 #player {
      position: absolute; // or "fixed"
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The # selector needs to be fixed as mentioned above, but if that still doesn't get the desired effect then take note of the `scale` param you are using. You might want to use `exactfit` instead. From Adobe's [doc](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/flash-object-embed-tag-attributes.html):

> **scale** -  Possible values: showall, noborder, exactfit, noscale. Specifies how Flash Player scales SWF content to fit the pixel area
>   specified by the OBJECT or EMBED tag.
>
> - **default** (Show all) makes the entire SWF file visible in the specified area without distortion, while maintaining the original
>     aspect ratio of the movie. Borders can appear on two sides of the
>     movie.
> - **noborder** scales the SWF file to fill the specified area, while maintaining the original aspect ratio of the file. Flash Player can
>     crop the content, but no distortion occurs.
> - **exactfit** makes the entire SWF file visible in the specified area without trying to preserve the original aspect ratio. Distortion
>     can occur.
> - **noscale** prevents the SWF file from scaling to fit the area of the OBJECT or EMBED tag. Cropping can occur.